# Oracle Wallet Integration in SSIS Oracle Provider OLEDB Connector

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, oledb, ssis-2012

I've successfully configured oracle wallet in my machine in windows 7. I also checked by executing the below command

```
sqlplus /@myoracleDB
```

and it gets connected to the DB successfully.

I'm trying to execute the SSIS package(DTSX) version 2012 in my machine. In the Data Flow task, I'm using Oracle Provider for OLEDB Connector. I wanted to connect the myoracleDB Database through oracle wallet in the OLEDB connector. I used the below configuration,

```
Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=MyOracleDB;OSAuthent=1;
```

But the Connection is failing with invalid username/password.

Please advise how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Try using `/` as login, blank password. That worked for me when i had "externally identified" logins setup on the server (basically windows trusted auth)

Comment: I used as you told, by keeping the User as "/" and it worked like a champ, Below is the detail.
Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=myoracleDB;OSAuthent=1;User ID=/

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid you have to write your comments as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I was using "externally identified" logins setup on the Oracle server (basically windows trusted authentication), I used

- `/` as login
- blank password

Inside my SSIS packages and it worked.

I don't know if this is the same as Oracle wallet - I don't think so, but try it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `OSAuthent=1;` you are trying to establish a `Trusted Connection` using the current `OS authentication`, then make sure that [you have authenticated the current user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/adapters-and-accelerators/adapter-oracle-database/connect-to-the-oracle-database-using-windows-authentication)

If you have the oracle login credentials try connecting using the following Connectionstring

```
Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=MyOracleDB;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Also you can use [Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-oracle)

```
Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=MyOracleDB;Integrated Security = SSPI;
```

**References**

- [Oracle provider for OLEDB connectionstrings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-provider-for-ole-db-oraoledb/)
- [Oracle connectionstrings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/)
- [Authenticating Database Users with Windows](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b32010/authen.htm#CHDHFFDC)

Comment: I want to use Oracle wallet usage in OLEDB Connector (Oracle Provided) in SSIS. Please advise me on this. The other references that you mentioned is fine, but I need solution for connecting OLEDB Connector (oracle Provided) through oracle wallet

Comment: The first part is using Oracle OLEDB connector. Just ignore the second part.